# SQL: SQL Exclusive Or

Tags: sql, oracle, xor

I have a table in the form:

```
username | role
---------+------
name1    | internal
name1    | admin
name2    | internal
name3    | admin
name4    | external
```

I need to find all users that have the role either 'internal or 'admin' but don't have both (essentially an XOR). How can I do this in SQL?

A query that results in a form similar to below would be perfect:

```
username | internal | admin
---------+----------+-------
name2    | 1        | 0
name3    | 0        | 1
```

If it helps I'm using an Oracle database

Comment: A very naive solution would be to count how many roles user has and then use `HAVING` to filter only those that have exactly 1 role.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would approach this with conditional aggregation:

```
select username,
       max(case when role = 'internal' then 1 else 0 end) as internal,
       max(case when role = 'admin' then 1 else 0 end) as admin
from t
where role in ('internal', 'admin')
group by username
having count(*) = 1;
```

If name/role pairs could be duplicated, then use `having count(distinct role) = 1`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
SELECT UserName, 
CASE WHEN Role = 'internal' Then 1 Else 0 END internal,
CASE WHEN Role = 'admin' Then 1 Else 0 END admin
FROM (
SELECT A.*, COUNT(DISTINCT Role) OVER (PARTITION BY UserName) CNT
FROM Users A
) WHERE CNT = 1
```

[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/dc42ba/3)